What are the differences, if any, between area chairs and senior area chairs for a conference?
What are the differences, if any, between area chairs and senior area chairs for a conference?
I am mostly interested in the conferences in the field of machine learning and natural language processing.

May well depend on the particular conference. I’m not familiar with the terms in my field.

@JonCuster thank you, I am mostly interested in the conferences in the field of machine learning and natural language processing.

https://qipeng.me/blog/what-does-an-area-chair-do/ Seems to cover it

Perhaps the area chair is the one who will do all the work, and the senior area chair is the one with the big name who will no little or no work (except possibly make more unnecessary work for the area chair).

Most of high ranked conferences that expect to receive a high volume of submission, the job of reviewing and quality assurance is done by employing area chairs (voluntary services) and senior area chairs (senior researchers). As explained in detail here and here, area chairs are lower in tier than their senior counterparts, and the senior ACs could accept or reject the recommendations made by the ACs.
